# Excel Automation Error - Formatting A Date

Tags: vba, excel

My code is below. I am trying to create a new sheet based on unique values in the `Date` column. If I don't format the date properly,

I get an invalid sheet name error, because of the `/`. However, when attempting to format the date to avoid this error, I get an automation error and the macro terminates at the last line that I have posted here.

Please help. :)

```
Sub Analyze()
Dim DateColumn As Range
Dim theDate As Range
Dim theNextDate As Range
Dim theWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim thenewWorksheet As Worksheet
Const DateColumnCell As String = "Date"
Set theWorksheet = Sheets("Main")
Set DateColumn = theWorksheet.UsedRange.Find(DateColumnCell, , xlValues, xlWhole)

'Make sure you found something
If Not DateColumn Is Nothing Then
    'Go through each cell in the column
    For Each theDate In Intersect(DateColumn.EntireColumn, theWorksheet.UsedRange).Cells
        'skip the header and empty cells
        If Not IsEmpty(theDate.Value) And theDate.Address <> DateColumn.Address Then
            'see if a sheet already exists
            On Error Resume Next
                Set thenewWorksheet = theWorksheet.Parent.Sheets(DateColumn.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0


            'if it doesn't exist, make it
            If thenewWorksheet Is Nothing Then
                Set thenewWorksheet = theWorksheet.Parent.Worksheets.Add
                thenewWorksheet.Name = Format(theDate.Value, "Long Date")
```

Comment: What is the Value of `theDate` when you run this?

Comment: You never check to see if `Worksheets(Format(theDate.Value, "Long Date"))` exists.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: It's hard for me to see what the problem is, but I notice you are testing using `DateColumn.Value` which would return an unformatted date, e.g., 1/1/2015 but you are naming the sheets using the long format, e.g., "Monday, January 1, 2015". These comparisons seem like they'd always be false. This is a good time to step through with F8 and check your variables in the Locals window.

Comment: @DougGlancy `theDate` is `6/3/2015`.

Comment: You may split your last line in two, `Dim sname As String : sname = Format(theDate.Value, "Long Date")` and `thenewWorksheet.Name = sname`, and see what is the value of `sname` you get, to clarify the source of error.

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you use the wrong value in

```
    Set thenewWorksheet = theWorksheet.Parent.Sheets(DateColumn.Value)
```

This should be `theDate.Value`, not `DateColumn.Value`.

But to handle the invalid format error, I suggest this extension to your code:

```
        Dim NewSheetName As String

        For Each theDate In Intersect(DateColumn.EntireColumn, theWorksheet.UsedRange).Cells
        'skip the header and empty cells
        If Not IsEmpty(theDate.Value) And theDate.Address <> DateColumn.Address Then
            'see if a sheet already exists
            NewSheetName = Format(theDate.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            Set thenewWorksheet = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
                Set thenewWorksheet = theWorksheet.Parent.Sheets(NewSheetName)
            On Error GoTo 0

            'if it doesn't exist, make it
            If thenewWorksheet Is Nothing Then
                Set thenewWorksheet = theWorksheet.Parent.Worksheets.Add
                thenewWorksheet.Name = NewSheetName
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Use a custom format for the date to make sure all characters contained are legal in a sheet's name. Secondly, look for the **same** string in existing sheets' names as the new sheet's prospective name.

**edit:**

Fixed another bug: the pointer `thenewWorksheet` is tested against `Nothing` to see if a sheet with that name already exists. In the next loop iteration, this pointer still points to the last sheet created! So the test will always be positive after the first sheet is created. To fix, reset the pointer prior to the test.